# Copy the contents of a 1D array to another by value in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to copy by value the contents of dynamically-allocated array `stillPlaying` to `tmpIntArray` as long as the value isn't `-1`, ie `tmpIntArray` should hold all the values that are in `stillPlaying`, sans the `-1`.

I get the error message `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector` when attempting to compile.

```
tmpIntArray = (int*) malloc(nParticipantsLeft*sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i < nParticipantsLeft; i++)
{
  if (stillPlaying[k] == -1)
     k++;
  tmpIntArray[i] = stillPlaying[k];
}
```

Thanks for helping me out with this hopefully easy question.

Declaration at the top of the file:

```
int * stillPlaying,  //points to array of IDs for players who are not out
      tmpIntArray;   //holds the intermediate version of stillPlaying
```

Comment: what you are trying to do is get a subscript of something that can't be subscripted. can you post the initialization of `tmpIntArray` and `stillPlaying`?

Comment: The code snippet seems alright. I think there's an issue somewhere else in the code.
I suggest you include more code.

Comment: Also note that this code is going to have extra space in tmpIntArray if `nParticipantsLeft > filtered(stillPlaying)`

Comment: Sean was right, what's the initialization of `tmpIntArray`? And which line has the compiling error?

Comment: `tmpIntArray` should have been declared `int *`, if so, this is fine.

Comment: And the initialization of `k` for that matter.

Comment: I must have a gap in my knowledge because I thought that `tmpIntArray = (int*) malloc(nParticipantsLeft*sizeof(int));` initializes the array.

Comment: When i is 0, what is the value of k?  You did not tell us that.

Comment: I get the same error when right after allocating space to `tmpIntArray` I put `tmpIntArray[0] = 7;`

Comment: What exactly is your code supposed to do? Because it seems that once `stillPlaying[k] != -1` it will keep adding the same player over and over .. seems useless to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the wrong declaration of `tmpIntArray` which should be `int *tmpIntArray`, I think the code itself should be this:

```
int j = 0;

for(i = 0; i < nParticipantsLeft; i++)
{
    if (stillPlaying[i] != -1) {
        tmpIntArray[j++] = stillPlaying[i];
    }
}
// j contains number of players in tmpIntArray
```

Comment: ah this is also true; didn't see it before. thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Change declaration to

```
int *stillPlaying,
      *tmpIntArray;  //Notice *
```

With your earlier declaration `stillPlaying` was `pointer` but `temIntArray` was `int` (not `pointer`)

Also, make sure you allocate memory for `tmpIntArray`

Comment: @Rob, Typo! Happens! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
{
    int stillPlaying[10] = {12,-1,-1,45,-1,34,12,-23,45,3};
    int *tmpIntArray;
    int i,k = 0;
    int nParticipantsLeft = 7; //Total number of Elements in stillPlaying - number of -1 Entries
    tmpIntArray = (int*) malloc(nParticipantsLeft*sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < nParticipantsLeft;)
    {
      if (stillPlaying[k] == -1)
      {
         k++;
      }
      else
      {
        tmpIntArray[i] = stillPlaying[k];
        i++,k++;
      }
    }

     for(i = 0; i < nParticipantsLeft; i++)
    {
        printf("Value at index %d = %d \n",i,tmpIntArray[i]);
    }
}
```

I think you want to eliminate the -1's entry and keep the rest in some array .

```
Test this code here : http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php
```

OK ,Since number of -1s are not known before doing the malloc , I think you can take sufficiently large size of it and then free it when you come to know the actual length of the tmpIntArray .

Comment: Will not filter out the elements in the Source array after 'nParticipantsLeft' .All will be zero after count nParticipantsLeft -1. CAn try with test array :   int stillPlaying[10] = {12,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-13,-1,-1,-12}; output should be 12,-13,12, in you case it will be 12,0,0.

Comment: Sorry, but that's nonsense. Jack's code and your code do the same thing; in both cases, the size of the `tmpIntArray` -- `j` for Jack's code and `i` for yours -- must be used instead of `nParticipantsLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int s[100], t[100], n, k;
    //whatever assignments have gone here
    k=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if(s[i]!=-1) {
            t[k]=s[i];
            k++;
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```